# First "If" Enemy Selection Function being recognized as a syntax error in Python

Tags: python

I have an issue with trying to under the syntax error with the line `if enemy_select = 1:` in this type of code:

```
enemy_select = random.randit(1, 11)

for enemy_select in range(1):
    if enemy_select = 1:
        enemy_type = character 1

    elif enemy_select = 2:
        enemy_type = character 2

    elif enemy_select = 3:
        enemy_type = character 3

    elif enemy_select = 4:
        enemy_type = character 4

    elif enemy_select = 5:
        enemy_type = character 5

    elif enemy_select = 6:
        enemy_type = character 6

    elif enemy_select = 7:
        enemy_type = character 7

    elif enemy_select = 8:
        enemy_type = character 8

    elif enemy_select = 10:
        enemy_type = character 9

    elif enemy_select = 10:
        enemy_type = character 10

    elif enemy_select = 11:
        enemy_type = character 11
```

Comment: What exactly does the syntax error say?

Comment: It just returns it as an invalid syntax

Comment: In the future, please try to reduce the problem before posting code - if all the trail `elif`s aren't part of the problem (i.e. problem remains unchanged after removing them), don't include them. Short, easy to read code is more likely to get get answers & often you resolve the issue on your own when narrowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you lack the correct indentation for all your lines after `for...`.

Add few spaces or tab at the beginning of every line, starting from first `if`.

**EDIT:**

I was wrong, the problem is that you're using `=` instead of `==` in `if` lines.

BTW: I've tried it in CMD window and it has shown me a `^` sign at the exact character that caused an error. May be helpful in the future.

Comment: Even after tabbing every line (Starting from 'if') it still says that there is a syntax error. Not to mention that wouldn't it give an indentation error if the indentation was incorrect?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Python, even though `=` instead of `==` is an error, wouldn't that be a logic error? As in the compiler can't catch it no matter what? At least that's the case in C.

Comment: In C you can write `if( i=1 )` and it compiles but C allows you to do a lot of such things. Python seems to be more restrictive and assignment operation is not the one he expects in an `if` statement, so it throws a generic "syntax error". I still agree that the message could be better.

Comment: Tried to fix it, just gave some generic "indentation error" or just replies a syntax error at the end of the code

Comment: Okay it worked thanks. I forgot to add a underscore at the final character sorry